# "Katalog mit" oder "Katalog über"

Tags: preposition

Gibt es einen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen den beiden Sätzen?
Welcher der Sätze klingt für euch besser?

> Wir senden Ihnen den aktuellen Katalog über unsere Produkte.
>
> Wir senden Ihnen den aktuellen Katalog mit unseren Produkten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beide Sätze sind korrekt. Man muss nur beachten, dass *über* hier den Akkusativ verlangt, während *mit* ein Objekt im Dativ benötigt. *Über* könnte auch zusammen mit dem Dativ verwendet werden, hat dann aber eine andere Bedeutung, die meist nicht dem entspricht, was man wirklich sagen will.

Auch *mit* und *über (+ Akk)* unterscheiden sich in der Bedeutung:

1. > Wir senden Ihnen den aktuellen Katalog **mit** unseren Produkten.

   Das kann auf zwei Arten interpretiert werden:

   1. Der Katalog beinhaltet Abbildungen und Beschreibungen der Produkte. Eigentlich (wenn man die Aussage ganz genau nimmt) wird hier ausgesagt, dass dich die Produkte selbst im Katalog befinden. Tatsächlich meint man damit aber, dass stattdessen nur Beschreibungen und Abbildungen enthalten sind (nicht die physischen Produkte).
   2. In dem Paket, in dem der Katalog verschickt wird, befinden sich außer dem Katalog auch einige Produkte, d.h. der Katalog liegt zusammen mit Produkten im selben Paket. In dieser Aussage ist keine Information darüber enthalten, wie Katalog und Produkte innerhalb des Pakets angeordnet sind.
2. > Wir senden Ihnen den aktuellen Katalog **über** unsere Produkte. *(Akkusativ)*

   Der Katalog liefert Informationen über die Produkte.

   Der Unterschied zu 1.1 ist sehr subtil. In 1.1 wird eigentlich ausgesagt, dass sich die Produkte im Katalog befinden. In 2. wird ausgesagt, dass etwas über die Produkte berichtet wird. Weil 1.1 aber immer so verstanden wird, dass sich anstelle der Produkte Beschreibungen im Katalog befinden, bedeuten 1.1 und 2 im Endeffekt dasselbe.
3. > Wir senden Ihnen den aktuellen Katalog **über** unseren Produkten. *(Dativ)*

   In der Praxis wird wohl kaum jemand diesen Satz so verwenden. Damit wird nämlich ausgesagt, dass sich irgendwo unten (vielleicht am Boden einer Schachtel?) die Produkte befinden, und darüber liegt der Katalog. Das ganze wird dann in dieser Konstellation versendet.

Answer (score 4):

> Wir senden Ihnen den aktuellen Katalog über unsere Produkte.
>
> Wir senden Ihnen den aktuellen Katalog mit unseren Produkten.

Beides gleich. Ich finde die Variante mit *über* holperiger, die zweite kann aber auch *zusammen mit* bedeuten, der Besteller bekäme also einen Katalog als Dreingabe. Das ist aber wohl nicht gemeint. Besser:

> Wir senden Ihnen den aktuellen Katalog unserer Produkte.

Mein Favorit:

> Wir schicken Ihnen unseren aktuellen Produktkatalog.

Answer (score 2):

Ein Katalog "mit unseren Produkten" ist ein Katalog, der unsere Produkte enthält - der Satz ist nicht falsch, er ist aber imho nicht gut, weil man ihn auch in der Praxis eher selten anwendet.
Ein Katalog "über unsere Produkte" impliziert, dass es weitere Informationen gibt; ein Katalog ist aber im Grunde genommen eine Auflistung mit Produktdetails. Weitere Ausführungen zu den Produkten erwartet man dort nicht (wie z.B. die Geschichte der Entwicklung dieses Produktes), man möchte Produktinformationen, Preise, Bestellnummern in einem Katalog übersichtlich dargestellt sehen. Der Satz ist zwar grammatikalisch richtig, ich bezweifelte aber, dass er in der Praxis verwendet wird. 
Ich würde hier immer den Genitiv verwenden: "ein Katalog unserer Produkte" oder wie oben schon genannt "... unser Produktkatalog". Gruß

Answer (score 0):

Beide Sätze sind umständlich und ungebräuchlich, letzterer außerdem zweideutig, da hier auch der Versand von Produkten nebst Katalog gemeint sein kann.

Der in der Realität vorkommende Satz lautet im Allgemeinen:

> Wir senden Ihnen unseren aktuellen Produktkatalog.

Comment: Antwortet überhaupt nicht die Frage welcher von den genannten Sätzen der bessere wäre.

Comment: @Beta: Nicht explizit, aus der Antwort geht aber hervor, dass der erste Satz weniger schlecht ist.

Comment: Deine Antwort impliziert aber - was meist richtig sein wird - dass Produkte und Katalog den selben Eigentümer/Besitzer haben. Denkbar ist, dass ein fremder Katalog eigene Produkte vorstellt und man diesen verschicken kann, etwa weil man Teil einer Genossenschaft ist. Zugegeben, sehr spitzfindig.